# how to push amend commit in Intellij IDEA 2019.1.3, it always create two independent commit in gerrite

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I push an amend commit to gerrite instead of creating new commit by Intellij IDEA? I have already check the 'amend' box but it does not work.

Intellij IDEA 2019.1.3

Answer (score 1):

Amending a commit changes its hash. Such commits have to be force-pushed, so probably that is the option you are looking for. Not sure what is the correct way to handle it in gerrit though.

To force push in IntelliJ, open Push dialog and chose the Force Push option form the Push button dropdown.

Comment: thanks so much that I have already check the 'amend' box and 'force commit' but it would produce two commit in gerrite. Had I chose 'override original old commit' before? Do you know the configuration then I can update? thanks.

Comment: hello: I have to close Intellij IDEA and go to BASH

Comment: it is ok now by bellow command lines:  <br/>

git add -A  <br/>
git status  <br/>
git commit --amend  <br/>
git review  <br/>

Comment: my question is WHY intellij IDEA does not work for amend commit?

Comment: Do you mean that when you commit in IntelliJ with the Amend checkbox set, commit is still not amended? Or ther issue is that pushing the amended commit to gerrit creates a separate commit in Gerrit? Note that there is no builtin Gerrit support in IntelliJ and you should probably use a plugin to work with it.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply and I used command line in bash to amend and that works.

Answer (score 0):

in new version of IntellijIDEA community 2020.2 it has been solved.

Comment: In IntelliJ 2022.1.3 amend commit doesn't seem to work again? or still?